# encode a list of strings to integers

Tags: python, string, list, encoding, integer

I have a list of strings:

`l = ["pear", "apple", "pear", "banana"]`

and would like to code each element as an integer, starting from 0 to the number of unique elements in the list, so the result would be

`[0,1,0,2]`

I can only think of complicated solutions, is there an easy one-liner for this?

Comment: Create a dictionary whose keys are the strings and values are consecutive numbers. Then use that to convert the list to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one line solution using numpy:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = ["pear", "apple", "pear", "banana"]

>>> [np.where(np.array(list(dict.fromkeys(l)))==e)[0][0]for e in l]
[0, 1, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not a one-liner, but a very simple solution:

```
>>> idx = {}
>>> for x in l:
...     if x not in idx:
...         idx[x] = len(idx)
...
>>> idx
{'pear': 0, 'apple': 1, 'banana': 2}
>>> [idx[x] for x in l]
[0, 1, 0, 2]
```

A more compact way to get `idx`, although, I think the above is easier to read/understand, but basically the same:

```
>>> idx = {}
>>> for x in l:
...     idx[x] = idx.get(x, len(idx))
...
>>> idx
{'pear': 0, 'apple': 1, 'banana': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary that maps each string to an id, then use `list()` and `map()` to map each string to its corresponding id. You could condense the dictionary index generation into one line using `.index()`, but it would likely be slower (since index would perform a linear search starting at the start of the list for each element, rather than constructing everything in one pass).

```py
data = ["pear", "apple", "pear", "banana"]

indices = {}
count = 0
for item in data:
    if item not in indices:
        indices[item] = count
        count += 1
        
result = list(map(lambda x: indices[x], data))
print(result)
```